# Nuget internet requirement

Tags: nuget

Having (presumably) understood the motivation behind Nuget, I want to know, whether we still require internet access to download a package which is already being downloaded earlier for different project in different solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can even set up your own feed stored on the file system as described [here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds).

Answer (score 1):

You can setup your own local NuGet repository as As Denis Ivin has already said.

NuGet also has its own local machine cache which keeps NuGet packages that you have installed previously (C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache). You can install these by selecting the Recent packages tab in the Manage Packages dialog.

Having your own local NuGet repository is probably better since the cache could be cleared.